# Compare any checksum with proposed checksum by website

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I often download files from the Web and many websites suggest to compare *a* proposed checksum with what I obtain from my computer (usually in Terminal).

However, as the checksums tend to be quite long 64 characters for `sha256` or 32 for `md5` for example, I was wondering if a universal Terminal line could be created to use what a website might propose as a checksum?

I found [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442960/how-to-automate-comparison-of-md5sum-hash-values-for-a-large-number-of-files/442968#442968) question that is similar to mine, however restricted to `md5sum`. What I would like is a little bit what the contributor suggest but with any checksum algorithm (e.g., `sha1`, `sha256`, `md5`, etc.):

```
$ echo "checksum_suggested_by_site_to_be_put_here  filetohashA.txt" | md5 -c -
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use similar commands for other types of checksums. Not sure what exactly you are looking for here?

Comment: @nohillside: I would like a command (similar to the one displayed in the question) that allows the use of any checksum algorithm that tells me whether the checksum matches or not. Something like this: step 1. have the generic command stored somewhere in the computer (e.g., Notes), 2. paste the checksum provided by the website at the appropriate place, 3. change the checksum command to the one requested by the website, 4. press enter, 5. Terminal tells me whether the the checksums (the one pasted and the one generated) match (or not). (shall I add this in my question?)

Comment: So basically you want a script which automatically determines the type of the checksum and then calls the correct command to verify it? Can you add the list of all checksum types you want to cover, ideally with samples (or a download link to a sample)?

Comment: **macOS** does not have the `md5sum` _utility_, but it has `md5` and `shasum` that you can use. In **Terminal**, `man md5` and `man shasum` to see what these _utilities_ offer. You can also use `openssl`, e.g. `openssl sha1 file` --  See: [openssl man page](https://ss64.com/osx/openssl.html)

Comment: @nohillside: not really automatically as there would be some copy/paste in the process. Say the website Y mentions that if one downloads file.txt the shasum checksum is 1a2b3c. What I would like is something as follows: compare 1a2b3c with shasum -a file.txt → if match then echo "ok", else echo "KO". And you would like to be able to swap shasum with md5, etc.

Comment: @user3439894: yes you are right. It was a paste from the AskUbuntu question. Apologies for creating the confusion. I corrected the line in the question.

Comment: `md5` doesn't have the `-c` _option_, but `shasum` does, however `shasum` doesn't generate `md5` hashes nor does `md5` generate `shasum` hashes, `osascript` can do both. Is there some reason you can't just generate the checksum and visually compare it? If not then I'd suggest you create an Automator _Service/Quick Action_ to achieve your goal. Which BTW is still not exactly clear what you want to do.

Comment: Well, it's rather easy to write a shellscript which you can call as `check_file_integrity md5 checksum file` or `check_file_integrity sha checksum file`, depending on the type. Or a script which just computes all the checksums you want to know and compares each with the "checksum" value you pass as an argument.

Comment: Have you looked at the free Checksum app in the Mac App Store? https://apps.apple.com/us/app/checksum/id1371978119?mt=12

Answer (score 4):

Here are two different approaches that can be taken, one using **Automator** and **AppleScript**, and the other using a `bash` *script* and **Terminal**.

**Using Automator and AppleScript**

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, used in an **Automator** *Service*<sup>1</sup>, set to **Service receives selected** `files or folders` **in** `Finder`, with a **Run AppleScript** *action*, will allow one to paste a copied **MD5**, **SHA1**, **SHA256** or **SHA512** *checksum value* into a *dialog box* and verify it against the selected *file* in **Finder**.

In **macOS High Sierra**, I saved the **Automator** *Service*<sup>1</sup> as **Verify Pasted Checksum**. Then in **Finder** selecting a downloaded *file* for which I had a *checksum* copied to the clipboard, I right-clicked it and selected **Verify Pasted Checksum** from the **Services** context menu. I then pasted in the copied *checksum* and pressed the **Enter** *key*. It then returned the appropriate message.

- <sub><sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave**, and later, an **Automator** *Service* is called a *Quick Action*. There are also other minor nomenclature differences but they should be more obvious when comparing them to pre-macOS Mojave Automator workflows.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
global pastedChecksum
global fileToCaculateChecksum

on run {input}

    set fileToCaculateChecksum to POSIX path of first item of input

    set pastedChecksum to text returned of (display dialog ¬
        "Paste checksum here:" buttons {"Cancel", "Verify Checksum"} default button ¬
        "Verify Checksum" default answer "" with title "Verify Checksum Matches Provided Value")

    set L to (length of pastedChecksum)

    if L = 32 then
        -- Validate MD5 checksum.
        set caculatedChecksum to do shell script "/sbin/md5 -q " & fileToCaculateChecksum's quoted form
        displayValidationMessage(caculatedChecksum)
    else if L = 40 then
        -- Validate SHA1 checksum.
        set caculatedChecksum to do shell script "/usr/bin/shasum " & fileToCaculateChecksum's quoted form & " | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}'"
        displayValidationMessage(caculatedChecksum)
    else if L = 64 then
        -- Validate SHA256 checksum.
        set caculatedChecksum to do shell script "/usr/bin/shasum -a 256 " & fileToCaculateChecksum's quoted form & " | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}'"
        displayValidationMessage(caculatedChecksum)
    else if L = 128 then
        -- Validate SHA512 checksum.
        set caculatedChecksum to do shell script "/usr/bin/shasum -a 512 " & fileToCaculateChecksum's quoted form & " | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}'"
        displayValidationMessage(caculatedChecksum)
    else
        -- Unrecognized checksum.
        display dialog "The length of the pasted checksum was not recognized!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Unrecognized Checksum" with icon caution
    end if

end run

on displayValidationMessage(caculatedChecksum)
    if pastedChecksum is equal to caculatedChecksum then
        -- Checksum matched.
        display dialog "The checksum for '" & fileToCaculateChecksum & "' matched!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Valid Checksum"
    else
        -- Checksum did not match.
        display dialog "The checksum for '" & fileToCaculateChecksum & "' did not match!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with title "Bad Checksum" with icon stop
    end if
end displayValidationMessage
```

- <sub>Scroll to see additional *code*.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

---

**Using bash and Terminal**

If you want a `bash` solution for **Terminal**, use the following *example* `bash` *code*, saved to a *file* and made *executable* with `chmod`.

In **Terminal**:

```
touch vpc
open vpc
```

Copy and paste the *example* `bash` *code*, shown further below, into the opened document, then save and close it.

Back in **Terminal**:

```
chmod u+x vpc
./vpc
```

Note: I used `vpc` for: [V]erify [P]asted [C]hecksum

You can also place the, e.g., `vpc` *executable* in a *directory* that is within your `PATH` and be able to use it without `./` or its *full qualified pathname*.

*Example* `bash` *code*:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "  Missing argument!"
    echo "  Uasge: vpc pasted_checksum filename"
    echo "  Example: vpc 98d9402a8b446bdd57b4b6729b4d575e /path/to/filename"
    exit 1
fi

l=$(/usr/bin/awk -v var="$1" 'BEGIN {print length(var)}')
[ -f "$2" ] || l=0

case "$l" in
    32 )
                # Validate MD5 checksum.
            c="$(/sbin/md5 -q "$2")"
        ;;
    40 )
                # Validate SHA1 checksum.
            c="$(/usr/bin/shasum "$2" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}')"
        ;;
    64 )
                # ValidateSHA256 checksum.
            c="$(/usr/bin/shasum -a 256 "$2" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}')"
        ;;
    128 )
                # Validate SHA512checksum.
            c="$(/usr/bin/shasum -a 512 "$2" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}')"
        ;;
    0 )
            echo "  Bad Filename!"
            exit 1  
        ;;
    * )
            echo "  Unreconized Checksum!"
            exit 1
        ;;                                      
esac

    # Verify checksum matches provided value, using case insensitive matching.
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $1 == "$c" ]]; then
    echo "  The checksum for '""$2""' matched."
else
    echo "  The checksum for '""$2""' did not match!"
fi
shopt -u nocasematch
```

- <sub>Scroll to see additional *code*.</sub>

---

<sub>**Note:** The *example* `bash` *code* contains some *error handling*. The onus is upon the user to add any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

Comment: @pdeli, I don't know when you last saw my answer, but wanted to let you know I added a `bash` solution too. If you found either method I've presented useful, please consider an up-vote and or marking it as accepted, thanks.